# How to show that the difference of this limit is $0$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose I have a positive function $f$, real numbers $a>0$, $y$ and a function $g:[0,\infty]\to\mathbb{R}$ such that

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}(g(x)-g(\infty))f(x)e^{ax}=y$$

Moreover, I have proven that $\lim\inf_{x\to\infty} f(x)e^{ax}>0$. Can we deduce that $\lim_{x\to\infty}(g(x)-g(\infty))=0$? How to prove this or what would be required to show this?

Comment: The functions are continuous?

Comment: How do you define $g(\infty)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example $f(x)=e^{-ax}$ (with $y \neq 0$) shows that the conclusion can fail unless $g$ is continuous at $\infty$.

Comment: What if $g(x)=e^x$ for $x\in[0,\infty)$ and $g(\infty)=0$ ?

Comment: @CSquared I has taken the domain of $g$ as $[0,\infty)$. I have corrected my answer. Thanks for yor comment.

Comment: thanks for your answer. How to prove this with assuming $g$ is continuous?

Comment: @swissy If $g$ is continuous then $g(x)\to g(\infty)$ as $x \to \infty$  (by continuity at $\infty$). There is nothing to prove and the other hypothesis is of no use.